# Provide support for ios6

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios5

Hi i have my app built for IOS version 5.1 but now i want to support it for IOS6 beacuse all my views on IPhone simulator for retina 4 inch has been moved upward . can you please help what is the easiest way to get around of this thing. because i have lot of views in my screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what you should do is create another XIB and just append it with "_iPhone5". Like this:

> ViewController1_iPhone5

In that xib set the Files Owner to the view controller, then relayout all your UI elements to your liking and set the outlets. Now, whenever you present this view controller, you want to check if the device is an iPhone 5, and adjust the nib name accordingly:

Define this in the Prefix file (a file that is imported to every single one of your created files, so if you import a class there all the files will have that imported). You can define it in your view controller if you don't want to in your Prefix file (should be found in your Supporting Files):

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs ( (double)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - ( double)568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

Then you can use this:

```
    if (IS_IPHONE_5 && [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    UIViewController *vc1 = [[MenuMileIndexViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"ViewController_iPhone5" bundle: nil];

   // present the view controller

}
```

If you are not using a XIB, and programmatically coding your views, use this:

```
        if (IS_IPHONE_5 && [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {


// Reposition and resize your subviews

}
```

NOTE: make sure you add the iPhone 5 default image

Comment: i am not using XIB is there any Other alternative

Comment: what do you mean you're not using a nib

Comment: I am manually creating the view with hardcode values there are no nib files in my project

Comment: I have all my views created in viewDidLoad method or init.

Comment: @Anshul updated answer, but how can you CREATE a view in viewDidLoad? Do you mean you position, size and add subviews

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18213/discussion-between-anshul-and-teendev)